# Permissions Block blank page

Tags: upgrade, magento1.9.2.3

My permissions blocks, permissions variables and index management pages are blank after a 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.3 upgrade.

I've been a Magento dev for years now but this one has me stymied:

- compilation is disabled
- caches cleared
- reindex via CLI completed, no problems to speak of
- no issues in system or exception logs
- apache logs are also clean
- I've checked local and community for admin overrides and not spotted any (although I do plan to run through this one again tomorrow with non-red eyes)

I have also been tempted to drop a fresh 1.9.2.3 on top of the install.

Has anyone experienced this particular issue in the context I'm describing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script to automatically add your blocks and variables.

https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox

How to use:

```
php -f fixSUPEE6788.php -- fixWhitelists
```

Comment: what a gorgeous little piece of machinery :)  I wish I knew about this a year ago.  Thank you so much for the recommendation.

Comment: just want to add another thanks here...this tool is a godsend for developers, can't thank you enough Rafael